# How to use the mapping in practice?

Tags: java, mapstruct

The example here: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/3457f37c24ea7799b0752cc7ee8307283ab09ad2/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/example/mapper/EmployeeMapper.java

The generated mapping will be like:

Employee toEmployee(EmployeeDto employeeDto, CycleAvoidingMappingContext context) {...}

In practice, how to get a valid CycleAvoidingMappingContext object ?

Answer (score 1):

You use the constructor.

```
new CycleAvoidingMappingContext()
```

When in doubt, look for unit tests.

https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles/src/test/java/org/mapstruct/example/EmployeeMapperTest.java#L59